# How update user info using its UID in a custom module?

Tags: users, database

We have a webform and when submitting this form we would like to update user info in the database regarding values of submitted Webform.

I already managed to get the submitted values from the webform in my custom module. But I don't know how to update the user info in the database because all user info are in separated tables.

*I can run a few update queries for each value but it's not a logical way for me!*

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can equally use either [`user_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_save/7.x) or [`field_attach_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_update/7.x).

```
// Load the user's account.
global $user;
$account = user_load($user->uid);
$edit = $account->field_my_custom_field[LANGUAGE_NONE][0][value] = $new_value;
user_save($account, $edit);
// field_attach_update
$account->field_my_custom_field[LANGUAGE_NONE][0][value] = $new_value;
field_attach_update('user', $account);
```

The difference between using one function or the other is that `user_save()` will update all the user fields whereas `field_attach_update()` will update only the specified field.

Comment: thx for ur answer, just a question, is this line getting the user ID and update it's profile '$account = user_load($user->uid);' ?

Comment: Welcome! No, you need the `$user->uid` to `user_load` a user and then when you `user_save` to update the user. The `uid` is a field attached to the `$user` entity, do a `describe users;` to your database and you will see all the available user fields. Thus, we are never getting the user id in the way you mean it, as a single/isolated value, instead, we are getting the user object with all its fields attached (from the db) and we decide to which field(s) to refer to.

Comment: Thx @mchar I understood :)

Comment: @Soheyl Using `user_load($user->uid)` is just an example. In your code you will use the user ID you have, if you have one, or the code shown in this answer, if you need to save a field for the currently logged-in user.